# query not giving result c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have tested this query in SSMS like this

```
SELECT     S_P_name, S_P_pack, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttoqty) / S_P_pack) AS ost, SUM(S_P_ttoqty) % S_P_pack AS otb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttsold) / S_P_pack) AS sst, 
                      SUM(S_P_ttsold) % S_P_pack AS stb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttqty) / S_P_pack) AS pst, SUM(S_P_ttqty) % S_P_pack AS ptb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttavail) / S_P_pack) AS ast, 
                      SUM(S_P_ttavail) % S_P_pack AS atb, CAST(SUM(S_P_ttavail * S_P_prate / S_P_pack) AS decimal(9, 2)) AS grs
FROM         STOCK
WHERE     (S_type <> 'phy') AND (Purchase_date BETWEEN '2014/1/25' AND '2015/12/25')
GROUP BY S_P_name, S_P_pack
```

and it is giving me desired result in that . but it is not working when i am implementing it with c# code.

here is what i did

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT S_P_name, S_P_pack, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttoqty) / S_P_pack) AS ost, SUM(S_P_ttoqty) % S_P_pack AS otb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttsold) / S_P_pack) AS sst, SUM(S_P_ttsold) % S_P_pack AS stb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttqty) / S_P_pack) AS pst, SUM(S_P_ttqty) % S_P_pack AS ptb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttavail) / S_P_pack) AS ast, SUM(S_P_ttavail) % S_P_pack AS atb, cast(SUM(S_P_ttavail*S_P_prate/S_P_pack)as decimal(9,2))AS grs FROM STOCK Where S_type<>'phy' AND Purchase_date between "+fromDate.ToShortDateString()+" And "+Todate.ToShortDateString()+" GROUP BY S_P_name, S_P_pack", conn);
            conn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                int i = 0;
                dgv1Clossing.Rows.Insert(i);
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_P_name"].Value = dr["S_P_name"].ToString();
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_P_pack"].Value = dr["S_P_pack"].ToString();
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_opn_strp"].Value = dr["ost"].ToString();
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_opn_tabs"].Value = dr["otb"].ToString();
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_pur_strp"].Value = dr["pst"].ToString();
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_pur_tabs"].Value = dr["ptb"].ToString();
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_sold_strp"].Value = dr["sst"].ToString();
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_sold_tabs"].Value = dr["stb"].ToString();
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_avail_strp"].Value = dr["ast"].ToString();
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_avail_tabs"].Value = dr["atb"].ToString();
                dgv1Clossing.Rows[i].Cells["S_avail_total"].Value = dr["grs"].ToString();
                i++;
            }
            conn.Close();
```

on debugging i found this is not throwing any exception or error . but it is not getting in the loop. `while(dr.read())` . there 3 related  rows in my table which are coming as result in SSMS but not in this.
help me to know ,where i am going wrong please.

Comment: Have you ever tried your `cmd` in your SSMS or something? This query returns data in there?

Comment: How do you write this in SSMS? `...between "+fromDate.ToShortDateString()+"....`

Comment: @Steve sorry for that , i have updated that query in question

Comment: You need to quote the dates and some spaces infront of the `as` are missing.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen where in cmd query

Comment: here:    `And '"+Todate.ToShortDateString()+"' GROUP`

Comment: It's better to use the `Parameters` instead of concatenate strings. because of vulnerability issues.
For more information about parameters, check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT S_P_name, S_P_pack, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttoqty) / S_P_pack) AS ost, SUM(S_P_ttoqty) % S_P_pack AS otb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttsold) / S_P_pack) AS sst, SUM(S_P_ttsold) % S_P_pack AS stb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttqty) / S_P_pack) AS pst, SUM(S_P_ttqty) % S_P_pack AS ptb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttavail) / S_P_pack) AS ast, SUM(S_P_ttavail) % S_P_pack AS atb, cast(SUM(S_P_ttavail*S_P_prate/S_P_pack)as decimal(9,2))AS grs FROM STOCK Where S_type<>'phy' AND Purchase_date between '"+fromDate.ToShortDateString()+"' And '"+Todate.ToShortDateString()+"' GROUP BY S_P_name, S_P_pack", conn);
```

Put this sqlcommmand and test it. I added `'` before and after date that you were missing.
Hope it will help you.

> Edited

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT S_P_name, S_P_pack, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttoqty) / S_P_pack) AS ost, SUM(S_P_ttoqty) % S_P_pack AS otb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttsold) / S_P_pack) AS sst, SUM(S_P_ttsold) % S_P_pack AS stb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttqty) / S_P_pack) AS pst, SUM(S_P_ttqty) % S_P_pack AS ptb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttavail) / S_P_pack) AS ast, SUM(S_P_ttavail) % S_P_pack AS atb, cast(SUM(S_P_ttavail*S_P_prate/S_P_pack)as decimal(9,2))AS grs FROM STOCK Where S_type<>'phy' AND Purchase_date between '" + fromDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") +"' And '" + Todate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") +"' GROUP BY S_P_name, S_P_pack", conn);
```

Comment: throwing exception "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: then convert it as fromDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") and similarly, Todate.ToString("yyyyMMdd").

Comment: like this '"+fromDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"'    ?

Comment: cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT S_P_name, S_P_pack, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttoqty) / S_P_pack) AS ost, SUM(S_P_ttoqty) % S_P_pack AS otb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttsold) / S_P_pack) AS sst, SUM(S_P_ttsold) % S_P_pack AS stb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttqty) / S_P_pack) AS pst, SUM(S_P_ttqty) % S_P_pack AS ptb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttavail) / S_P_pack) AS ast, SUM(S_P_ttavail) % S_P_pack AS atb, cast(SUM(S_P_ttavail*S_P_prate/S_P_pack)as decimal(9,2))AS grs FROM STOCK Where S_type<>'phy' AND Purchase_date between '" + fromDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") +"' And '" + Todate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") +"' GROUP BY S_P_name, S_P_pack", conn);
try it

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SqlParameter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Directly inserting parameters to string query in C# is always discouraged.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT S_P_name, S_P_pack, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttoqty) / S_P_pack) AS ost, SUM(S_P_ttoqty) % S_P_pack AS otb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttsold) / S_P_pack) AS sst, SUM(S_P_ttsold) % S_P_pack AS stb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttqty) / S_P_pack) AS pst, SUM(S_P_ttqty) % S_P_pack AS ptb, FLOOR(SUM(S_P_ttavail) / S_P_pack) AS ast, SUM(S_P_ttavail) % S_P_pack AS atb, cast(SUM(S_P_ttavail*S_P_prate/S_P_pack)as decimal(9,2))AS grs FROM STOCK Where S_type<>'phy' AND Purchase_date between @FromDate And @Todate GROUP BY S_P_name, S_P_pack", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add(
"@FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fromDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add(
"@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Todate;
```